# 10 webworkers created, but only 9 returning a value

Tags: javascript, web-worker

So I'm basically doing a lot of operations on objects in an array. So I decided to use webworkers so I can process them in a parallel manner. However, if I inputted an array with 10 objects, only 9 workers would return a value. So I created this simple mockup that reproduces the problem:

```
var numbers = [12, 2, 6, 5, 5, 2, 9, 8, 1, 4];
var create = function(number) {
    var source = 'onmessage = function(e) { postMessage(e.data * 3) }';
    var blob = new Blob([source]);
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    return new Worker(url)
}; 

var newnumbers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    var worker = create();
    worker.onmessage = function(e) {
        newnumbers.push(e.data);
        worker.terminate();
    }

    worker.postMessage(numbers[i]);
}
```

So basically, each number in de array gets multiplied by 3 and added to a new array `newnumbers`. However, `numbers.length = 10` and `newnumbers.length=9`. I have debugged this for quite a while and I verified that 10 workers were created.

I feel like i'm doing something stupidly wrong, but could someone explain?

[Run it here on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wagenaartje/bqf5e9o1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `terminate` on the last worker before it processes the messsage, so the last worker is not outputting anything.

This is happens because the `worker` variable is actually a global variable instead of a local one. You can replace `var worker` with `let worker` to make it a local variable. If you are worried about `let` browser compatibility use an `Array` to store the workers, or simply create a function scope`.

Now, terminate is called on the last worker because the `var worker` variable will be set to the last worker when the loop ends. Note that the loop will complete executing before any worker will start processing (as the loop is synchronous code).

In your original code instead of calling `terminate()` on each worker you would call 10 times `terminate()` on the **last** worker.

```
var newnumbers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    let worker = create();
    worker.onmessage = function(e) {
        newnumbers.push(e.data);
        worker.terminate(); // "worker" refers to the unique variable created each iteration
    }
    worker.postMessage(numbers[i]);
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/bqf5e9o1/2/

Comment: Definitely fixed it, so are all workers also terminated correctly that way?

Comment: Yes, as the `worker.terminate()` call will happen for each worker created at each iteration. In your implementation with the global `var worker` variable `worker.terminate()` was called 10 times on the last worker only.